# how can i print a specific portion of array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print a number from an array. But when i do this:

```
echo $results[0][0];
```

i get error.I tried to print the whole array using print_r() function

```
echo print_r($results);
```

Then i get this result:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [lastOrderProcessedNumber] => 109089875875875 ) ) 1
```

I just need to print "109089875875875" this number

How can i do that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: You can clearly see the property name `lastOrderProcessedNumber`. Why do you think you should use `[0]`?

Comment: Why are you using both `echo` and `print_r`? `print_r()` doesn't return anything useful, it prints the data itself.

Comment: Sorry for that! I really got confused;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print_r()` is a great way to inspect the contents of a variable.  What it is showing you is that your variable holds an array whose first element (at index 0) is an object with an `lastOrderProcessedNumber` attribute.  In PHP, you use `->` to access object properties, so you should be able to retrieve the `109089875875875` value like this:

```
$results[0]->lastOrderProcessedNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the `print_r` result, the indexed result is an object:

```
// $results is an 'Array' (access with square brackets)
Array
(
  // Index 0 is an Object (access with arrow operator)
  [0] => stdClass Object
  (
    [lastOrderProcessedNumber] => 109089875875875
  )
)
```

This means you have to access the property through the arrow operator, like so:

```php
$results[0]->lastOrderProcessedNumber
```

If you're expecting to only have one result, or to grab the first result from `$results`, you can make use of [`reset`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php):

```php
reset($results)->lastOrderProcessedNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see *$results* is an array of objects, that means that *$results[0]* is an object, not an array, so you can't access its attributes as an array but instead as an object. Like this:

```
$results[0]->lastOrderProcessedNumber;
```